# Casting char array into int array using atoi

Tags: c, arrays, casting, char, atoi

Hello I'm attempting to convert a char into an int.  I have a char array that was inputted through `scanf`, "10101" and I want to set an int array's elements equal to that char arrays elements.

example input:

> 10101

```
char aBuff[11] = {'\0'};
int aDork[5] = {0};

scanf("%s", aBuff); //aBuff is not equal to 10101, printing aBuff[0] = 1, aBuff[1] = 0 and so on
```

Now I want `aDork[0]` to equal `aBuff[0]` which would be `1`.
Below is what I have so far.

```
//seems to not be working here
//I want aDork[0] to  = aBuff[0] which would be 1
//But aDork[0] is = 10101 which is the entire string of aBuff   
//aBuff is a char array that equals 10101
//aDork is an int array set with all elements set to 0

int aDork[5] = {0}
printf("aBuff[0] = %c\n", aBuff[0]); //value is 1
aDork[0] = atoi(&aBuff[0]); //why doesnt this print 1? Currently prints 10101
printf("aDork[0] = %d\n", aDork[0]); //this prints 1

printf("aBuff[1] = %c\n", aBuff[1]); //this prints 0
printf("aBuff[2] = %c\n", aBuff[2]); //this prints 1
```

Comment: Casting is (forced) type-conversion. Not parsing, like `atoi`.

Comment: so if I want each element of the char array to become a literal int 1 or int 0 how can I achieve this?

Comment: the difference between a char number and a int number (of one digit) is 0x30 ('0') so: aDork[0] = aBuff[0]-'0';  aDork[1] = aBuff[1]-'0';  etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask:

```
aDork[0] = atoi(&aBuff[0]); // why doesnt this print 1? Currently prints 10101
```

It does so because:

```
&aBuff[0] == aBuff;
```

they're equivalent. The address of the first element in the array is the same address you get when referencing the array itself. So you're saying:

```
aDork[0] = atoi(aBuff);
```

which takes the whole *string* at `aBuff` and evaluates its integer value. If you want to get the value of a *digit*, do that:

```
aDork[0] = aBuff[0] - '0';   // '1' - '0' == 1, '0' - '0' == 0, etc.
```

and now

```
aDork[0] == 1;
```

Working example: https://ideone.com/3Vl3aI

Comment: wouldn't I have to know what aBuff[1] is equal to?  For example, if I want aDork[1] = aBuff[1] and I don't know if aBuff[1] is equal to '1' or '0', I wouldn't just be able to write aDork[1] = aBuff[1] - '0' because this would produce 1?

Comment: No. If `aBuff[1] == '0'`, then `aBuff[1] - '0'` is the same as `'0' - '0'`, which is of course `0`. See the example - it converts all the digits to integers in the `aBuff` array.

Answer (score 1):

this code is working as expected, but you are not understanding how atoi works:

> Now I want aDork[0] to equal aBuff[0] which would be 1

but

> `aDork[0] = atoi(aBuff);`

means aDork[0] will store the integer value of aBuff. Meaning the value 10101 and not the string "10101"

PS: you didn't need an array of char for aDork:

```
int aDork = 0;
aDork = atoi(aBuff);
```

is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `aBuff` contains a string of zeros and ones (that does not exceed the length of `aDork`), the following would transfer these values to an integer array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(aBuff); i++)
{
    aDork[i] = (aBuff[i] - '0');
}
```